# Progress monitor for eclipse plugin in multi threaded environment

Tags: java, eclipse, multithreading

I have an eclipse plug in which is multi threaded application. For multi threading I have used ExecutorFramework

I have a main class where there are 3 major functions [ analysis1(),analysis2(),analysis3()] which uses multi threading.

```
Class Testing{
    initialization();
    analysis1();
    .....
    ....
    analysis2();
    ....
    if(condition) {
       analysis3()
    }
```

Say initilaization() corresponds to 10%, and analysis1(),analysis2() and analysis3() 40%,10%,40% respectively

all analysis1() ,analysis2() and analysis3() looks something like below
where I have sued monitor

```
            exeService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(coresNumber);

            ExecutorCompletionService<Void> exeCompletionService = new ExecutorCompletionService<Void>(
                    exeService);
            List<Future<Void>> futures = new ArrayList<Future<Void>>();
            int workPerUnit = percentfunc/ futures.size();
            for (int i = 0; i < futures.size(); ++i) {

                Future<Void> future = exeCompletionService.take();
                monitor.worked(workPerUnit); 
                if (null != monitor && monitor.isCanceled()) {
                    if (exeService != null) {                         
                        exeService.shutdownNow();
                    }
                    return Status.CANCEL_STATUS;
                }
                future.get();
            }
```

percentfunc is the percent I gave for each major functions.

I have a problem that monitor will complete 100% even before it executes second major function. What should be done to resolve this.

I have not considered multi threading for reporting the progress. Any idea on how to use it is appreciated.

I also have to consider execution of analysis3() is optional sometimes. In that case initialization(),analysis1(),analysis2() together should make 100%.